# How to avoid pulling down of screen on iPhone app

Tags: jquery, ios, css, iphone, cordova

I am developing an app for iPhone, but my app screen can be pulled down and up if i drag with finger. I want header and footer to keep fix and content of page can be pulled down and up. And also want to change screen appears after pulling down and up should be grey instead of black. I am using xcode5 with cordova (phonegap). Please help.
Thanks you.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using phonegap 3 + then add

```
  <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
```

to config.xml

[image]

Comment: It Worked!!!! thanks @Arjun.  grt job! can you tell me now to fix header and moveble inner screen with grey background

Comment: use css overflow property ,

Answer (score 5):

if you're using Cordova 2.3.0+ find config.xml and add this line:

```
  <preference name="UIWebViewBounce" value="false" />
```

or in Cordova 2.6.0+:

```
  <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
```

Comment: thanks @milind, i will try and let you know.
Any idea how to change that black color below puled screen to grey in screen?

Comment: @Sushant:this will prevent pulling of screen. will let you if i can get something about color change .

Answer (score 0):

Complete in your app config.xml file next line:
    - DisallowOverscroll ->> true
    - Delete any metatag like height=device-height in your html (Cordoba file).
For background black color see if this helps:  [phonegap ios7 select dropdown gets black background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19123848/phonegap-ios7-select-dropdown-gets-black-background)

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your code

```
<div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false">
```

Hope this will help

Answer (score 0):

Try the following script, your issue will be resolved.

```
// Function to disable "pull-to-refresh" effect present in some webviews.
// Especially Crosswalk 12 and above (Chromium 41+) runtimes.
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    var lastTouchY = 0;
    var maybePreventPullToRefresh = false;

    // Pull-to-refresh will only trigger if the scroll begins when the
    // document's Y offset is zero.

    var touchstartHandler = function(e) {
        if (e.touches.length != 1) {
            return;
        }
        lastTouchY = e.touches[0].clientY;
        // maybePreventPullToRefresh = (preventPullToRefreshCheckbox.checked) && (window.pageYOffset == 0) ;

        maybePreventPullToRefresh = (window.pageYOffset === 0);
        //document.getElementById('txtLog').textContent = "maybePreventPullToRefresh: " + maybePreventPullToRefresh;
    };

    // To suppress pull-to-refresh it is sufficient to preventDefault the
    // first overscrolling touchmove.

    var touchmoveHandler = function(e) {
        var touchY = e.touches[0].clientY;
        var touchYDelta = touchY - lastTouchY;
        lastTouchY = touchY;

        if (maybePreventPullToRefresh) {
            maybePreventPullToRefresh = false;
            //if (touchYDelta > 0) {
            e.preventDefault();
            //document.getElementById('txtLog').textContent = "TouchY: " + touchYDelta;
            // console.log("pull-to-refresh event detected") ;
            return;
            //}
        }

        // if (preventScrollCheckbox.checked) {
        //     e.preventDefault() ;
        //     return ;
        // }

        // if (preventOverscrollGlowCheckbox.checked) {
        //     if (window.pageYOffset == 0 && touchYDelta > 0) {
        //         e.preventDefault() ;
        //         return ;
        //     }
        // }
    };



    document.addEventListener('touchstart', touchstartHandler, false);

    document.addEventListener('touchmove', touchmoveHandler, false);

});
```